# Subscription billing for SaaS model with free IOS App

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, saas

I am currently working a on a product that my customers will be paying me monthly for. Their product is just a web application but their clients will all be able to download a free IOS or Android app. For their clients to login they will be issued a login from my customers web application. The free app is completely optional for my customers clients. My customers will be able to use the web application even without any of their clients using the app.

My question is... will I have to pay Apple a percentage of the website subscription costs to my customers?? The app experience to the clients of my customers is completely free. If I do have to pay Apple how would I even go about this? It would be very silly for my customers to have to pay in-app when they dont even use the app.

Just wondering if any IOS developers have run into a similar situation and how you handled it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would not have to pay apple, but you would have to make sure that the app itself does not link to (or possibly mention) the external payment system. It would be fine if the app allows logging into a paid account, just not purchasing from the app, while circumventing apple's payment system. You could also consider allowing payments with in app purchases being optional, for app users, with others paying through other means.

See point 11.13 [at the app store review guidelines page](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/).

An example of a system like this is visible in the Amazon Kindle app for iOS, where you can log into your amazon account and read books you have purchased with the account, but cannot buy books through the app.

EDIT: however see point 11.12 in the link above, you may need to use in app purchases for users who use the app as it says "Apps offering subscriptions must do so using IAP, Apple will share the same 70/30 revenue split with developers for these purchases". You should still be able to offer a seperate subscription for non-app users.

EDIT 2: As in point 11.14 If your app is providing approved content ("magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, video and cloud storage") you can "read or play approved content...that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the App, as long as there is no button or external link in the App to purchase the approved content. Apple will only receive a portion of revenues for content purchased inside the App."

Relevant guidelines:

11.12:

> Apps offering subscriptions must do so using IAP, Apple will share the same 70/30 revenue split with developers for these purchases, as set forth in the Program License Agreement

11.13:

> Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the App, such as a "buy" button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected

11.14:

> Apps can read or play approved content (specifically magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, video and cloud storage) that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the App, as long as there is no button or external link in the App to purchase the approved content. Apple will only receive a portion of revenues for content purchased inside the App

11.15:

> Apps may only use auto-renewing subscriptions for periodicals (newspapers, magazines), business Apps (enterprise, productivity, professional creative, cloud storage), and media Apps (video, audio, voice), or the App will be rejected

Comment: Thank you for all the information. I am still not sure what the answer is after reading your edits though. My customers will not be profiting off of the app or anything. The free app is just a way for easier communication for my customers and their clients. If I am not offering a subscription to the app user but instead to the user of my web applicaton does your first edit still apply to my model?

Comment: The app is just a way for the users to pay my customers (credit card/ach) or submit requests to ease communication. It does not offer any sort of goods or services except for the payments and communication

Comment: In that case you should be fine with offering the app for free, and the first edit does not apply. athough apple may not approve the payment portion of the app. It would probably be best if the app was limited to communication, using an external method for payments.

Comment: You're welcome. note that I edited my last comment regarding payment information (if you didn't see it).